# Is there a Nova way to display inline the results of a HasMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel-nova

I have the following structure

- Route
- HasMany Steps

With a single Nova row in my Route view, I want to display the results of that relationship like so:

| Route Name | Some Route Detail | Steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RouteA | ABC | - |
| RouteB | DEF | StepA, StepB |
| RouteC | GHI | StepC |

What I currently have in my `Route.php` Nova file is like:

```php
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            Text::make('Route Name', 'name')->sortable()->copyable(),
            Text::make('Some Route Detail', function () {
                return $this->getSomeRouteDetail();
            })->onlyOnIndex(),
            HasMany::make('Steps', 'steps', \App\Nova\SomeModule\Step::class),
        ];
    }
```

... but that results in a structure like

| Route Name | Some Route Detail |
| --- | --- |
| RouteA | ABC |
| RouteB | DEF |
| RouteC | GHI |

| Route Name | Steps |
| --- | --- |
| RouteB | StepA, StepB |
| RouteC | StepC |

This is my first time working with PHP so please let me know if there is something else I can do to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Would need to see more of your Model/Migrations structure to know for sure, but if you only want it displayed like that on the index, one option can be:

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Text::make('Route Name', 'name')->sortable()->copyable(),

        Text::make('Some Route Detail', function () {
            return $this->getSomeRouteDetail();
        })->onlyOnIndex(),

        HasMany::make('Steps', 'steps', \App\Nova\SomeModule\Step::class)
            ->hideFromIndex(),

        Text::make('Steps', 'step_names')
            ->onlyOnIndex()
    ];
}
```

Then on your Model:

```php
class Route extends Model
{
    ...
    public function getStepNamesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->steps->pluck('name')->implode(', ');
    }
}
```